# Multiplication of numbers as string

Tags: java

Why is `'0'` subtracted from `n1.charAt(i)` and `n2.charAt(j)`?

Question: Given two numbers represented as strings, return multiplication of the numbers as a string.

```
public String multiply(String num1, String num2) {
    String n1 = new StringBuilder(num1).reverse().toString();
    String n2 = new StringBuilder(num2).reverse().toString();

    int[] d = new int[num1.length()+num2.length()];

    //multiply each digit and sum at the corresponding positions
    for(int i=0; i<n1.length(); i++){
        for(int j=0; j<n2.length(); j++){
            d[i+j] += (n1.charAt(i)-'0') * (n2.charAt(j)-'0');
        }
    }

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    //calculate each digit
    for(int i=0; i<d.length; i++){
        int mod = d[i]%10;
        int carry = d[i]/10;
        if(i+1<d.length){
            d[i+1] += carry;
        }
        sb.insert(0, mod);
    }

    //remove front 0's
    while(sb.charAt(0) == '0' && sb.length()> 1){
        sb.deleteCharAt(0);
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: try these: `System.out.println((int) '0');` and `System.out.println((int) '3');`, then you will understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is '0' subtracted from n1.charAt(i) and n2.charAt(j) ?

Because the number of the Unicode character representing the digit 0 is 48, not 0.

Imagine you wanted to label 'A' => 0, 'B' => 1 etc... then you'd use

```
n1.charAt(i) - 'A'
```

etc... but as it happens, we want '0' => 0, '1' => 1 etc, so we subtract '0'. You need to differentiate between "the value, as an `int`" and "the character, as a `char`" (where the latter still has a number value, but it's not what you might expect it to be).

Answer (score 3):

It's calculating (by subtraction) the numeric value of the character. The character constant `0` is also digit `0`. Consider a loop of the `char` value '0' to '9' can also be done as an `int`.

```
for (char ch = '0'; ch <= '9'; ch++) {
    System.out.print(ch);
    System.out.print(" = " );
    System.out.println((int) ch);
}
```

or

```
for (int ch = '0'; ch <= '9'; ch++) {
    System.out.print((char) ch);
    System.out.print(" = " );
    System.out.println(ch);
}
```

which (both) demonstrate the [ascii code](http://www.ascii-code.com/) (technically Unicdoe, but the technique predates Unicode) values for the digits

```
0 = 48
1 = 49
2 = 50
3 = 51
4 = 52
5 = 53
6 = 54
7 = 55
8 = 56
9 = 57
```

See also [`Character.digit(char, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#digit%28char,%20int%29) which  returns *the numeric value of the character `ch` in the specified radix.* Which means you could replace

```
d[i + j] += (n1.charAt(i) - '0') * (n2.charAt(j) - '0');
```

with

```
d[i + j] += Character.digit(n1.charAt(i), 10)
    * Character.digit(n2.charAt(j), 10);
```

of course, the method could be implemented with a call to the Java built-in arbitrary precision type `BigInteger` and you could use [`BigInteger.multiply(BigInteger)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#multiply-java.math.BigInteger-) like

```
return new BigInteger(num1).multiply(new BigInteger(num2)).toString();
```

Answer (score 2):

Subtracting '0' from a character that contains a digit gives you the numeric value of that character.

For example, '9' - '0' gives you the integer 9.

The reason for that is that the digit characters ('0' to '9') have integer values from 48 to 57, so '9' - '0' is equivalent to 57 - 48, which gives you 9.

Answer (score 0):

When a character is stored in an integer it is converted to it's corresponding  `ASCII` value stored.

Now the ASCII value of:

```
'0' (zero as character) is -> 48   
'1' (one as character ) is -> 49
 ......................
 and so on...
```

> Now, how can we get the integer  out of the character ?

Its easy to  subtract `48` from all  numeric character and which is ASCII of  `'0'`